# How to ordering the z-index in this case

Tags: html, css, z-index

There is an element that has 3 layer . For example:

book layer , adv layer and black layer

The div structure of them are

```
<div id="black"></div>
<div id="book">
    <div id="adv"></div>
</div>
```

(black is absolute, book is relative, adv is absolute)

The problem is , if I would like the black layer is above book but under adv , how can I achieve this without changing the structure?

Comment: You'll have to change the **HTML** structure to achieve this.

Comment: Would you mind provide some example? <div id="book>
<div id="adv"></div></div> can not change since the size of book affect the size of adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Got it:

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdharrington/343fL/)!

#### HTML

```
<div id="black"></div>
<div id="book">
    <div id="adv"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#black{
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left:20%
    z-index:1;
}
#book {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: pink;
    z-index:-1;
}

#adv{
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left:40%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

#### The Z-index highlights

```
#book{ 
z-index: -1;
}
#black{ 
z-index: 1;
}
#adv{ 
z-index: 2;
}
```

Your main problem will be aligning the elements unless you wrap them all in a div with position:relative

Answer (score 0):

I have test it,i think this css help you to create that structure of layer as you want.

Background color is used for differentiate layers.

```
#black{width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
top: 187px;}
#book
{
width: 585px;
height: 230px;
background: pink;
padding: 92px;
}

#adv{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
top: 187px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But It seems this stylesheet can not achieve the adv overlap layer , layer overlap book effect

Comment: If you are using this structure of Division in a static content then it seems to be nice and if you are using any further effects then you should think best suitable structure for your design. Exactly i need to know what look you want to give your web page.